# How the red circle marked equations came ?

Tags: ratio

Yesterday I started to learn algebra with my own. And the first chapter which I'm learning is Ratio . I'm not getting the red circle marked lines in the below image. I tried to understand it but didn't get it.

Thankyou in advance. and sorry for my bad English. :)

[image]

Comment: please can you explain me how?

Comment: I turned the comment into an answer, and if you don't know how to solve two equations with two unknowns, that book is probably not on the right level for you at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the first equation by $\frac{-a_2}{a_1}$ and add it to the second to get,
$$\Big(\frac{-a_2b_1}{a_1} + b_2  \Big)\frac{y}{z} +  \frac{-a_2c_1}{a_1} + c_2 = 0$$
$$\Big(\frac{-a_2b_1 + a_1b_2}{a_1}\Big)\frac{y}{z} +  \frac{-a_2c_1 + a_1c_2}{a_1}= 0$$
$$\Big(-a_2b_1 + a_1b_2\Big)\frac{y}{z} + -a_2c_1 + a_1c_2= 0$$
$$\Big( a_1b_2 - a_2b_1\Big)\frac{y}{z} = a_2c_1 - a_1c_2$$
$$\frac{y}{z} = \frac{c_1a_2 - c_2a_1}{ a_1b_2 - a_2b_1}$$
$\frac{x}{z}$ can be found in a similar way.

$$\frac{x}{z} = \frac{b_1c_2 - b_2c_1}{a_1b_2 - a_2b_1}$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{b_1c_2 - b_2c_1} = \frac{z}{a_1b_2 - a_2b_1}
\end{equation}
$$\frac{y}{z} = \frac{c_1a_2 - c_2a_1}{a_1b_2 - a_2b_1}$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{y}{c_1a_2 - c_2a_1} = \frac{z}{a_1b_2 - a_2b_1}
\end{equation}
From the above equations we have,
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{b_1c_2 - b_2c_1} = \frac{y}{c_1a_2 - c_2a_1} = \frac{z}{a_1b_2 - a_2b_1}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

The first pair of equations is essentially [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) applied to the system of equations given above that:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x/z\\y/z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-c_1\\-c_2\end{pmatrix}\implies
\frac{x}{z}=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}-c_1&b_1\\-c_2&b_2\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\end{vmatrix}},\;\frac{y}{z}=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_1&-c_1\\a_2&-c_2\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\end{vmatrix}},$$

To obtain the second circled equation, observe that the first circled pair has $z$ in the denominator of the left hand side, and $a_1b_2-a_2b_1$ in the denominator on the right. Multiplying both equations by $z$ and dividing by the numerator on the right you get $\frac{z}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}$ as the right hand side of both equations, so you can combine them into a single equation.

Answer (score 0):

The first set of equations comes from solving the two equations with two unknowns right above. The book presumably has a section on how to do that.

The second set comes from the first by multiplying with $z$ and diving by $b_1c_2-b_2c_1$.

Comment: it's not given. Can you explain me please

Comment: You're probably going to run into other things that the author of the book assumes you know about, so I would advise you to find a book that's more suited for your level.

Comment: can you tell me from which book I can learn such type of problems.Your advice will be very helpful.

Comment: I basically only know the books I used at university, and that's 12-20 years ago, so many of then probably can't be bought anymore, but for that stuff it was "Linear Algebra" by Robert Messer. My advice would be to ask someone closer, they might also have an understanding of your level, and might be able to recommend books in your native language.